# Nested IF statements

Tags: java, design-patterns

I often get in situation where I need to write such a code as below
Any design pattern for doing this neatly without a flood of IF statements  -

```
A obj = new A();
B obj2 = new B();

for ( i = 1 ; i < 20  ; i ++ )  {

if( i == 1 ) 
  obj.setField1(obj2.getOption1())
else if ( i == 2 ) 
  obj.setField1(obj2.getOption2())
else if ( i == 3 ) 
  obj.setField1(obj2.getOption3())

And so on.. for 20 times .. 

obj.setField2(obj2.getNonOptionField2());
obj.setField3(obj2.getNonOptionField3())

}
```

**EDIT -**

Analogy to looping here is that I am looping on a database and each record creates 20 more records in some other table. IN the 20 records, most columns  are same except the one I added condition on.

YEah design is not the greatest, but I don't have option.

Comment: You can use switch case.

Comment: It's not at all clear why you're using a loop here at all.

Comment: write a function `getOption(i)` for `B` class ?

Comment: There seems to be something wrong with your design...

Comment: My experience is that this kind of problems often occur when you dont but enough thought behind your code, many times problems like this can be solved using polymorphism.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In cases when an action is conditioned upon an integer value, you can create a `Map<Integer,MyAction>`, where `MyAction` is an interface that you define for this specific purpose. Put implementations of `MyAction` into the map to correspond to the integer options, and call actions in run-time in response to the values coming in:

```
interface MyAction {
    void setField(A obj, B obj2);
}
...
Map<Integer,MyAction> actionByNumber = new HashMap<Integer,MyAction>();
actionByNumber.put(1, new MyAction() {
    void setField(A obj, B obj2) {
        obj.setField1(obj2.getOption1());
    }
});
actionByNumber.put(2, new MyAction() {
    void setField(A obj, B obj2) {
        obj.setField1(obj2.getOption2());
    }
});
...
A obj = ...
B obj2 = ...
for (int i = 0 ; i != 20 ; i++) {
    MyAction action = actionByNumber.get(i);
    if (action != null) {
       action.setField(obj, obj2);
    }
}
```

Comment: Isn't this as complicated as the code above, just to match on numbers?

Comment: @Kata This is just an illustration, stripped down to its skeletal essence (i.e. putting action objects into a map). I am sure that the OP did not show his real code - the code in the post is only an illustration as well.

Comment: @fortm Yes, this approach certainly has a lot in common with the command design pattern. I did not call it the command design pattern to avoid unnecessary glorification of a somewhat simple implementation-level trick.

Comment: @dasblinkenlight - I am wondering if Class A is not fixed, but Class B is fixed. This only means that we need to set multiple targets with fixed source. That case, should I have a wrapper class to shield Interface MyAction from being aware of Targets as Class A1, class A2 .. ? So interface MyAction becomes - void setField(WrapperTArget obj, B obj2); B ofcouse is source

Comment: @fortm The interface is entirely up to you. Since the pairing of numbers and their actions is done by a map, it is entirely OK to have uptyped parameters (i.e. `java.lang.Object`) in place of a wrapper, knowing that the action will perform the correct cast anyway. It is also OK to pass multiple objects for `A` (I mean `A1 a1, A2 a2, A3 a3`) and let actions selectively pick the `A` objects that they would like to operate on. The idea is to pass full context to the `setField` method; the particular way of passing this context is entirely up to you.

Answer (score 2):

Try using a [switch case](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/switch.html) instead.

For example, your code would be:

```
for ( i = 1 ; i < 20  ; i ++ )  {
    switch(i){
        case(1): obj.setField1(obj2.getOption1());
                 break;
        case(2): obj.setField1(obj2.getOption2());
                 break;
        case(3): obj.setField1(obj2.getOption3());
                 break;
    }
}
```

Comment: As far as readability or maintainability is concerned, `switch` is in no way an improvement over a sequence of `if`s. Performance is a different concern, but I'm pretty certain that the OP is very well aware of the existence of the `switch` statement :)

Answer (score 1):

One option is a `switch` statement.

Another option is to make `obj2` keep an array of options, and access it by index. Something like:

`obj.setField1(obj2.options[i]);`

People will argue about the O-Oness of this, but you could dress it up in an accessor method.

Answer (score 0):

+1 to dasblinkenlight's use of interface and the pattern as suggested.  A growing if/switch is often a code smell that indicates some OO refactoring is appropriate.  You could add a method to pass in new MyAction instances to the map.  The benefit of this approach over *if* and *switch* constructs is that:

1 - implements the Open to extension, closed to modification policy.  You want to add a new behaviour?  No need to add another condition to an ever-growing original class, you just create a new implementation of MyAction and pass it in.

2 - behaviour can be altered runtime by changing the content of the map.

depending on your exact requirement, you may not need a actionByNumberto be a Map, maybe a list would do, ordered or sorted if necessary.